# PowerShell Out-file manipulation

Tags: powershell

i hope someone can help.
I am trying to manipulate a file created by powershell.
I managed to get to the end result that i want, but i am sure it would be easier if it was only one command.

```
# Invoke the Exchange Snapping ( make sure you are Exchange Admin to do it SO)
add-pssnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010

#Create a file with list of DL in the organization
Get-DistributionGroup | Select-Object Name | Out-File C:\Pre_DLGroups.txt
$content = Get-Content C:\Pre_DLGroups.txt

#Remove the 3 first lines of the file that you dont need it
$content | Select-Object -Skip 3 | Out-file C:\DLGroups.txt

#Trim the space in the end and crate the Final file
Get-Content C:\DLGroups.txt | Foreach {$_.TrimEnd()} | Set-Content c:\FinalDLGroup.txt
```

is that way to make the end result in a single file rather than creating 3?
cheers

Elton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Get-DistributionGroup | 
Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name -Skip 3 |
Set-Content c:\FinalDLGroup.txt
```

Comment: Hi Shay Levy,Thanks for mind blowing head shaker. I have been reading many articles of yours on forums, especially technet and your blog.

Answer (score 1):

You can send your content across the pipeline without writing it out to files.  You can use parenthesis to group the output of certain sets of cmdlets and/or functions, and then pipe that output through to the intended cmdlets.

This can all be applied on a single line, but I've written it here on multiple lines for formatting reasons.  The addition of `Out-String` is something of a safety measure to ensure that whatever output you're intending to trim can actually be trimmed.

Since we're not getting this content from a text file anymore, powershell could possibly return an object that doesn't understand `TrimEnd()`, so we need to be ready for that.

```
(Get-DistributionGroup | Select-Object Name) | 
Out-String | 
Select-Object -Skip 3 |
Foreach {$_.TrimEnd()} | 
Set-Content c:\FinalDLGroup.txt
```

However, an even smaller solution would involve just pulling each name and manipulating it directly.  I'm using `%` here as an alias for `Foreach-Object`. This example uses `Get-ChildItem`, where I have some files named test in my current directory:

```
(Get-ChildItem test*) | 
% { $_.Name.TrimEnd() } | 
Set-Content c:\output.txt
```